# XSLT Transformation under .net - Passed in node from XPath has no value

Tags: .net, xslt, .net-4.0, msxml

All,

I am using .net 4.0, and the old deprecated XslTransform() class to perform a transformation of an xml order to an html output.
I have an javascript function that is passed in a node w/ the following xpath expression:

```
<xsl:value-of select="user:renderNode(//items/item/Comments[string-length(text()) > 0])" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

I have verified using an xpath tool that the XPath expression returns me a node  which contains text content. Unfortunately, in the javascript function itself, when I say

```
return node.CurrentPosition;
```

or

```
return node.Current.InnerXml;
```

the position is 0, and InnerXml returns the entire order instead of my text selection.

Here's the C# code:

```
var t = new XslTransform();
        t.Load("res/order.xsl");
        t.Transform("res/order.xml", "res/output.htm");


        string output;
        using (var reader = File.OpenText("res/output.htm"))
        {
            output = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

And XSLT:

```
    <msxsl:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="user">
    <![CDATA[
        function renderNode(node) {
            return node.Current.InnerXml;

        }


    ]]>
</msxsl:script>

    <tr>
                    <td colspan="6">
                        <xsl:value-of select="user:renderNode(//items/item/Comments[string-length(text()) > 0])" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: You will need to tell us whether you use .NET with `XslTransform` or MSXML as these are different processors. If you use .NET then on the JScript side you need to write code that expects an XPathNavigator or an XPathNodeIterator.

Comment: If you look at above, I stated that I am using XslTransform() in System.Xml.Xsl, .net 4.0. My understanding is (may need correction) that when the javascript code block runs, it uses the MSXML processor, correct?

Comment: And your subject says MSXML. And why do you expect some `nodeValue` or `text`? Anyway, within .NET an XSLT/XPath node-set like selected by `//items/item/Comments[string-length(text()) > 0]` is represented as an `XPathNodeIterator` so you will have to write JScript code using that API and not some MSXML API.

Comment: The 'MSXML' and my lack of use of it in .net is the lack of knowledge on my part. So, you're saying is that the JS function executes not under MSXML api but another API which is .net XML run-time?

Comment: Yes, `XslTransform` is a pure Microsoft .NET implementation of an XSLT 1.0 processor integrated in the .NET framework, it works with XPathNavigator and XPathNodeIterator as the .NET types that are exposed for a single node in XSLT respectively a node-set.

Comment: Thx, Martin, you are absolutely right. I have updated my code but now my current node iterator doesn't point to my selection. See my updated example above. It appears, it points to the root. Why?

Comment: An `XPathNodeIterator` needs to be consumed with `MoveNext()` before being in a meaningful state. Simply accessing `Current` doesn't get you what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample runnable with `XslTransform` and .NET, the XSLT is

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl mf"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <msxsl:script implements-prefix="mf" language="JScript">
  function foo(nodeIterator) {
    if (nodeIterator.MoveNext()) {
      return nodeIterator.Current.Value;
    }
    else return '';
  }
  </msxsl:script>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="mf:foo(root/item)"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

as you can see on the XSLT side a node-set is selected by `root/item` and inside the JScript function an `XPathNodeIterator` is received and processed.

With an input XML of

```
<root>
  <item>foo</item>
</root>
```

that sample outputs a result document fragment with the string value `foo`.